# WSL Gazebo crashes upon opening

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, ros

I'm currently trying to run Gazebo on WSL in Ubuntu, using Xming, however, it crashes without even fully opening. I can see the orange loading screen when I call it through terminal `roslaunch turtlebot_gazebo turtlebot_world.launch`, however, it almost immediately dies.

It's pretty frustrating, as I've been working for this issue for a whole day now.

Here's what I get in the terminal:

```
[ERROR] [1523362032.530757200, 0.140000000]: Failed to load nodelet 
[/depthimage_to_laserscan] of type 
[depthimage_to_laserscan/DepthImageToLaserScanNodelet] even after refreshing 
the cache: Failed to load library 
/opt/ros/kinetic/lib//libDepthImageToLaserScanNodelet.so. Make sure that you 
are calling the PLUGINLIB_EXPORT_CLASS macro in the library code, and that 
names are consistent between this macro and your XML. Error string: Could 
not load library (Poco exception = libopencv_core3.so.3.3: cannot enable 
executable stack as shared object requires: Invalid argument)
[ERROR] [1523362032.532002600, 0.140000000]: The error before refreshing the 
cache was: Failed to load library 
/opt/ros/kinetic/lib//libDepthImageToLaserScanNodelet.so. Make sure that you 
are calling the PLUGINLIB_EXPORT_CLASS macro in the library code, and that 
names are consistent between this macro and your XML. Error string: Could 
not load library (Poco exception = libopencv_core3.so.3.3: cannot enable 
executable stack as shared object requires: Invalid argument)
[FATAL] [1523362032.535886600, 0.150000000]: Failed to load nodelet 
'/depthimage_to_laserscan` of type 
`depthimage_to_laserscan/DepthImageToLaserScanNodelet` to manager 
`laserscan_nodelet_manager'
[ INFO] [1523362032.705052600, 0.240000000]: Physics dynamic reconfigure 
ready.
[depthimage_to_laserscan-10] process has died [pid 1086, exit code 255, cmd 
/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/nodelet/nodelet load 
depthimage_to_laserscan/DepthImageToLaserScanNodelet 
laserscan_nodelet_manager image:=/camera/depth/image_raw scan:=/scan 
__name:=depthimage_to_laserscan __log:=/home/elona/.ros/log/aefadb42-3cb7- 
11e8-b57b-54ee75bf6d3f/depthimage_to_laserscan-10.log].
log file: /home/elona/.ros/log/aefadb42-3cb7-11e8-b57b- 
54ee75bf6d3f/depthimage_to_laserscan-10*.log
```

I've followed everything from [here](https://answers.ros.org/question/238646/installing-ros-on-ubuntu-bash-in-windows-10/).

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @PranshuMalik unfortunately no